# nginx: [error] failed to initialize Lua VM

Tags: nginx, lua, valgrind, centos7

I am trying to check memory leaks in my modules of nginx with valgrind.I am trying the following command

valgrind --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck --show-reachable=yes --log-file="/tmp/val.out" -v /usr/local/nginx -c /usr/local/conf/nginx.conf

I am getting the error **nginx: [error] failed to initialize Lua VM**

I am using nginx-1.6.2 on Cent OS 7 wit lua 0.9.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was fixed by upgrading Valgrind and adding some additional flags to LuaJIT compilation.

Look into:

- https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/681
  Specifically:

  - > ==52538== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX;
  - > Your version of valgrind does not support the MAP_32BIT flag required by LuaJIT's own allocator. You need either an older version of valgrind (like 3.8.1) or a newer version (like 3.11.0).
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openresty/riEO_YXTwz4
  Specifically (using Google translate):

  > This is because LuaJIT own memory allocator MAP_32BIT use this flag in Linux x86_64 above to call mmap () 
  >   System call. And Valgrind 3.9.0 is no longer supported from the mmap MAP_32BIT this flag, it will make LuaJIT 
  >   Initialization failed.
  >
  > The solution is to re-compile a special version of LuaJIT, force it to use a dispenser system, using a command like this at compile time LuaJIT:
  >
  > make CCDEBUG=-g Q= XCFLAGS='-DLUAJIT_USE_VALGRIND -DLUAJIT_USE_SYSMALLOC'
  >
  > Here the most important thing is LUAJIT_USE_SYSMALLOC this macro. Of course, for best results, you should also specify the following C compiler options:
  >
  > -DLUA_USE_APICHECK -DLUA_USE_ASSERT